# Gitlab Pages - Webpack project - error 404

Tags: webpack, gitlab

I have a simple project bundled with webpack, which I pushed to my GitLab. By default webpack creates the index.html inside a /dist folder. I want to learn how to configure the .gitlab-ci.yml file to create a static webpage in GitLab Pages. I tried the GitLab Pages tutorial, but didn't find a way to specify the path of the index.html file and my deployment shows a 404 error.
  Do I have to push the node_modules folder to my project for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First deployment can take about 20 minutes. Also, check permissions in project settings.

> GitLab will always deploy your website from a very specific folder called public in your
>   repository

[Gitlab docs](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/index.md)

```
image: alpine

pages:
  script:
  - mv ./dist ./public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```